# Windows DNS Migrations - new IP

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, migration

So I want to add two new servers to the Domain (Currently, I only have two) so that would make it 4 (Lets call the new ones 03 and 04).  However, I am eventually getting rid of the original (lets call them 01 and 02) as they are Windows 2003 R2 machines and my two new ones are 2008 R2.

How would I migrate all my machines from the IP Addresses of 01/02 to the new promoted DNS Addresses on 03/04?

Here's the example:

OLD

- DC01 - 192.168.10.1
- DC02 - 192.168.10.2

NEW

- DC03 - 192.168.0.3
- DC04 - 192.168.0.4

The new DC's haven't been promo'd into the domain.  I was going to add them in this week.  What I want to know is, currently, all of our systems are on 10.1 and 10.2 as primary/secondary.  How do I make the two new DC's (03 and 04) the new primary and secondary DNS for all of our servers so I can get rid of 10.1 and 10.2 and decommission DC01/02

Comment: When you're ready to retire 01 you add its IP as a secondary IP on 03 and likewise for 02 and 04. Does that fit your question? It's not 100% clear to me what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't want to keep the IP Addresses on 01 or 02 as we are getting rid of that subnet.  03 and 04's IP Addresses need to be the new primary and secondary DNS for the domain.

Comment: So would it be enough to just change the DHCP options for DNS servers?

Comment: Ok I edited the question (Not sure why DHCP is being discussed...)

Comment: I wouldn't change IP spaces entirely. I can't think of a way to do that without downtime. Do you have to change IP spaces? Either way, the only ways to change a devices primary and secondary name servers is either DHCP changes or manually change the ip settings.

Comment: We're doing this during a maintenance window so yes, downtime is fine.  I am just trying to get an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25142/discussion-between-todd-wilcox-and-matthew-dartez).

Comment: Don't update domain controllers AND change IP spaces at the same time. That way lies madness. Either change all of your IP addresses with downtime and then replace AD servers without downtime or replace AD servers without downtime and then change IP spaces with downtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the new dcs are installed and functioning and they contain the same dns information they can be used for dns resolution.

To change servers to use them you have 3 options.

1) manually remote desktop to each server and enter them in the adapter properties.
2) if the servers are getting their ip from a dhcp server you can just update the scope settings and do a releae and renew.
3) you can use powershell and a list of server names to make the changes. Something along these lines http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since what you're specifically asking about isn't totally clear, I'll just give the entire process for replacing Windows domain controllers, and I'll assume you must change the IP spaces. I'll also assume you have a way for the two IP spaces to communicate (a router or something).

1. Make sure the two new servers can ping the old domain controllers and have the old DNS servers listed as their DNS servers.
2. Add the new servers to the domain.
3. Add the Active Directory and DNS Server roles to the new servers.
4. Make sure the DNS information is up to date on the new servers for the Windows domain in question and change the new servers to use themselves and each other for DNS resolution.
5. Update all devices, especially domain-joined computers, that used to use the old servers for DNS so that they now use the new servers for DNS. You can do this by changing DHCP scope options or by manually changing their IP configurations.
6. Transfer the FSMO roles from the old AD servers to one or both of the new ones.
7. Uninstall DNS from the old AD servers.
8. Run dcpromo on the old AD servers to uninstall Active Directory.
9. (Optional) Remove the old servers from the domain. Power down the old servers and dispose of them.